# Checking for a value on selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some pretty simple validation that I'm working on, but it seems like I'm repeating myself a bunch of times. There has to be a better way of doing this. I'm simply checking if there is a value filled in for specific fields and apply a color if the value isn't filled in. There are also other areas where the validation is different where I'm checking a valid phone number. So I couldn't simply apply this to all inputs. Here's some of my code:

```
var x = $();
var pass = true;

function validateForm(){
        x = $('input#zip').val();
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            $('#ziplabel').css('color','#fff');
            pass = false;
        } else {
            $('#ziplabel').css('color','#444');
        }
        x = $('input#fname').val();
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            $('#fnamelabel').css('color','#fff');
            pass = false;
        } else {
            $('#fnamelabel').css('color','#444');
        }
        x = $('input#lname').val();
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            $('#lnamelabel').css('color','#fff');
            pass = false;
        } else {
            $('#lnamelabel').css('color','#444');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, you can iterate the input fields. For this sort of thing you should also be using classes, instead of inline CSS. Using jQuery `.each` and `.togggleClass` you can create something like this:

```
function validate () {

  $('#form input').each(function () {
     var $el = $(this)
     $el.prev('label').toggleClass('invalid', $el.val()); 
  });

}
```

And your stylesheet has a rule like this;

```
label {
  color: #444;
}

label.invalid {
  color: #fff;
}
```

If you want to check if the form was valid then you can check for the existence of a field with that class. `$('#form input.invalid').length`. Or you can set a boolean in the each function if you want to separate the logic from the HTML.

Comment: You could avoid the caching line if you use `$(this).prev('label').toggleClass('invalid',this.value)`